# put the value as an argument of a function?

Tags: php, mysql

supposed a variable named `$xlnum` value is as this `20,4,56,987,68,96.....`the variable $xlnum value is input by the vistor.

the next i will passed the value to a  sql query. if the value is one. that i can know how to do it. eg:

```
$result=mysql_query("select nid,title form node where nid=20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->nid;
    echo $row->title;
}
```

but now the value is `20 4 56...`,i want to loop out all the nid and title of `20,4,56,987,68,96.....`how do i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

```
$result = mysql_query("select nid,title form node where nid IN ($xlnum)");
```

But you need to validate that it contains sane values.

Assume `$xlnum = '20,4,56,987,68,96';` in these examples. Both end up with `$sql` that you can pass to `mysql_query`.

#### Option 1

```
// remove white space
$xlnum = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $xlnum);

// make sure the string is nothing but numbers separated by commas
if (!preg_match('/^(\d+,)*\d+$/', $xlnum))
  die("invalid format");

$sql = "select nid,title form node where nid IN ($xlnum)";
```

#### Option 2

```
$nids = array();
// loop through each comma delimited value
foreach (explode(',', $xlnum) as $nid)
{
  // force the value to an integer
  $nid = (int) $nid;

  // if it is non-zero add it to the list
  if ($nid) $nids[] = $nid;
}

// if the array is empty, nothing valid was entered
if (!$nids)
  die("invalid format");

// recreate the comma delimited string 
$xlnum = implode(',', $nids);

$sql = "select nid,title form node where nid IN ($xlnum)";
```

These are just two different ways to make sure the input is valid. The second is slightly different in that it will just ignore the pieces that are invalid.

I prefer something more like the second since it's easy to accidentally mess up a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

why not using [`WHERE ... IN`](http://data.agaric.com/mysql-where-1-4-5-syntax)

```
where nid in (2,3,4.....)
```

Comment: if the variable $xlnum value is input by the vistor.namely. you don't know what value are in the () how do i do?

Answer (score 1):

if $xlnum is an array you could do something like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("select nid,title from node where nid in (".implode(',',$xlnum).")");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->nid;
    echo $row->title;
}
```

If $xlnum is really just a string with comma separated numbers then just put the $xlnum inside the () without imploding.